# How to automatically connect Grafana (with PostgreSQL instead of SQLite 3) to Prometheus when using Helm

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, prometheus, kubernetes-helm

I am using **Helm** as for **Kubernetes** deployment (Grafana and Prometheus) specifically. I have specified **values.yaml** files for both of them. It works amazingly.

Since I have changed **Grafana** datasource from default **sqlite3** to **PostgreSQL** - data-source configuration is now stored in **PostgreSQL database**.

Well, the problem is that in my **values.yaml file* for **Grafana** I have specified datasource as following:

```
datasources: {}
datasources.yaml:
  apiVersion: 1
  datasources:
  - name: on-premis
    type: prometheus
    url: http://prom-helmf-ns-monitoring-prometheus-server
    access: direct
    isDefault: true
...
...


grafana.ini:
  paths:
    data: /var/lib/grafana/data
    logs: /var/log/grafana
    plugins: /var/lib/grafana/plugins
  analytics:
    check_for_updates: true
  log:
    mode: console
  grafana_net:
    url: https://grafana.net
  database:
  ## You can configure the database connection by specifying type, host, name, user and password
  ## # as separate properties or as on string using the URL property.
  ## # Either "mysql", "postgres" or "sqlite3", it's your choice
    type: postgres
    host: qa.com:5432
    name: grafana
    user: grafana
    # If the password contains # or ; you have to wrap it with trippel quotes. Ex """#password;"""
    password: passwd
    ssl_mode: disable
```

Unfortunately this does not take an effect and I have to configure connection to in **Grafana web interface** manually - which is not what I need. How do I specify this section correctly?

```
datasources: {}
datasources.yaml:
  apiVersion: 1
  datasources:
  - name: on-premis
    type: prometheus
    url: http://prom-helmf-ns-monitoring-prometheus-server
    access: direct
    isDefault: true
```

Answer (score 1):

remove '{}' after section datasources.
like this

```
    datasources:
      datasources.yaml:
        apiVersion: 1
        datasources:
        - name: Prometheus
          type: prometheus
          url: http://prometheus-server
          access: proxy
          isDefault: true
```